# Error while importing resources from Robot Framework Folder structure

Tags: automation, robotframework

I am trying to import keywords/variables/configs from different files in robot framework. The import seems to work fine as I am able to press ctrl+click and go to that resource file that means IDE is recognizing it. But the actual variables are not getting imported from the files.

**Folder Structure**

[image: folder structure]

**test_config.robot**

```
*** Variables ***
${BASE_URL}    https://www.example.com
${BROWSER}    Chrome
```

**test_data.robot**

```
*** Variables ***
${BASE_URL}    https://www.example.com
${BROWSER}    Chrome
${UsernameField}    id=txtUsername
${PasswordField}    id=txtPassword
${LoginButton}    id=btnLogin
${NameField}    id=txtName
${EmailField}    id=txtEmail
${RegisterButton}    id=btnRegister
${SearchField}    id=txtSearch
${SearchButton}    id=btnSearch
${ErrorMessage}    css=.error-message
${NoResultsMessage}    css=.no-results-message
```

**Login_test.robot**

[image: Login_test.robot file]

**Login_keywords.robot**

[image: Login_keywords.robot]

When I am trying to run login_test.robot. I am getting

```
\resources\keywords\common_keywords.robot' on line 3: Processing variable file '../variables/test_data.robot' failed: Importing variable file '../variables/test_data.robot' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '.'
```

I am not sure why IDE is throwing an error even though the import looks fine, I've tried importing with the full path but that also didn't work. Looking forward to some suggestions on what's missing or what's the possible reason for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to python and "physical robots" (as the `robot` tag states)? Please remove unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File you are trying to import with `Variable` command is not a variable file. See RF documentation: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#toc-entry-372

You must import this as a resource file like this:

```
Resource    ../resources/variables/test_data.robot
```